# How do I split an array (or csv string) into separate columns in the db, in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model (share) in which I save who can edit a lesson.
It is separated from the user model, and from the lesson model.
The data is currently saved as

```
|share_id | lesson_id | shared_ids |
|    2    |     23    | "45,66,21" |
```

Where "shared_ids" are the user ids that can edit the lesson

I would like to split it into

```
|share_id | lesson_id | shared_ids |
|    2    |     23    |    "45"    |
|    3    |     23    |    "66"    |
|    4    |     23    |    "21"    |
```

I have managed to split the shared_ids, but it is currently saved as one array inside the table :

```
|share_id | lesson_id |   shared_ids   |
|    2    |     23    | "45","66","21" |
```

Thanks for your help.

---- Edit ----
The Share class looks like that:

```
class Share < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :shared_token, :shared_ids
  belongs_to :lesson

  attr_reader :shared_token
  serialize :shared_ids
  # @Todo: save each seperately #
  def shared_token=(ids)
    self.shared_ids = ids.split(",")
  end
end
```

---- Edit 2 -----
The form for shared_token in the lesson view:

```
<%= f.fields_for :shares do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.label :shared_token, "Type the user names you wish to share the lesson with:" %>
  <%= builder.text_field :shared_token, "data-pre" => @shared_ids %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? It looks like you figured out how to split the string into an array. Couldn't you now just loop over the array and create a new record for every id and delete the existing one?

Comment: @Beerlington I am having a problem with where to loop the array.
I have updated the question with the class

Comment: How is the shared_token= method being called? How much control do you have over the code and DB design?

Comment: @Beerlington shared_token is called via attr_reader. I have full control over the code & db design.

Comment: Right, but what code are you using to set it? i.e. controller, view (form?)

Comment: @Beerlington it's a form.
I have updated the question to display the code for the form

Comment: I am confused.  Do you want to refactor your db or are you trying to reformat your data with each restful request?  If it's the former, I think you want to take the code you have already written and place it into a rake task.  Alternatively, you could make it a part of a migration file, which has it's own +'s and -'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Shares are children of Lessons, I think you might want to write a methed in your Lesson model that would iterate through the ids in a list (which you've already figured out how to generate) and create a Share for each id. something like...

```
def build_shares_from_list(ids)
    ids.each do |id|
        @share = self.shares.build({:share_ids => id})
        @share.save
    end
end
```

Then call that from your Lesson controller, and point your form to the appropriate controller action.

Comment: Thanks. One newbie question: in the lesson controller, how do I pass the ids list to the method above?

Comment: When your form passes data to a controller it's in a hash called "params", so params[:shared_token] is your raw string, and you already know how to split it ... params[:shared_token].split(",") ... I recommend you look at the scaffolding code Rails can generate to understand how data is passed between view, controller, and model. in the end you'll just pass the list as an argument into the method, like @lesson.build_shares_from_list(list_of_ids), but since the details of your application design are up to you, you gotta show your controller code if you want more concrete advice...

Answer (score 0):

how about a pure SQL solution (havent tested the code, just a general direction)

1. remove the quotes
   update shares set share_ids = replace(share_ids, '"', '');
2. create a temp table which will replace the old one once we're done
   create table _shares (share_id, lesson_id, shared_ids);
3. add the first shared_id from existing lists:
   insert into _shares select share_id, lesson_id, substring(shared_ids, 0, locate(shared_ids, ",")) from shares where shared_ids like '%,%';
4. remove the first shared_id from the existing lists:
   update shares set shared_ids = substr(shared_ids, locate(shared_ids, ",") + 1) where shared_ids like '%,%';
5. repeat 3, 4 until 0 records updated - no more shared_ids with "," - all are single values
6. add the remaining values - last value in the original ids list, or values which had just one value to begin with:
   insert into _shares select share_id, lesson_id, shared_ids from shares;
7. replace tables
   drop table shares; alter table _shares rename shares;
   (or, if there are constraints there: truncate table shares, insert into shares select * from _shares;